# Tex File No Longer Compiles

Tags: texlive

The file below was compiling just fine under official repository texlive versions for fedora 18 and 19. I switched to fedora 22 and started having issues (see error log below).

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\lstdefinelanguage[trace]{java}[]{java}{
  morekeywords={java.lang.ArithmeticException,Division.java,Affichage.java}
}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{MidnightBlue}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,1}
\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}

\begin{document}

\title{Assurance Qualité du Logiciel}
\subtitle{05 - Contrôle de la Qualité Logicielle}
\author{Mohamed Anis Mekki}
\institute{Institut Supérieur de Gestion de Tunis}
\date{\tiny{2014-2015}}

\lstset
{
  language=java,
  tabsize=2,
  alsodigit={-},
%  frame=lines,
%  caption=Le XSD Correspondant,
%  label=lst:xsd:sample2,
  frame=shadowbox,
  rulesepcolor=\color{gray},
%  xleftmargin=20pt,
%  framexleftmargin=15pt,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bf,
  commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize,
  emph={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l},
  emphstyle={\color{orange}}
}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Test par Couverture des Conditions - Variantes (Exemple)}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{
\lstinputlisting{code/Boolean.java}
}
&
\parbox{0.45\linewidth}{\scriptsize{
\begin{itemize}
 \item {\color{myBlue}{\textbf{Lignes $2-14$}}} formule de la décision,
 elle contient $3$ conditions (prédicats).
 \item {\color{myBlue}{\textbf{Lignes $3-5$}}} Première condition de la décision,
 elle contient deux sous-expressions \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{(a && !b)}} et \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{(c || d)}}.
 \item {\color{myBlue}{\textbf{Lignes $7-9$}}} Condition $2$.
 \item {\color{myBlue}{\textbf{Lignes $11-13$}}} Condition $3$.
\end{itemize}
Ici \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{a}}, \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{b}}, \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{c}},
 \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{d}}, \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{e}}, \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{f}},
 \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{g}}, \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{h}}, \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{i}},
 \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{j}}, \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{k}} et \colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{l}}
 sont des conditions atomiques.
}}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Console Errors:

```
*****
*****     PDFLaTeXsortie: 
*****     cd "/home/mekkimoh/Documents/QSFSI_2015"
*****     pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode QSFSI-05-Controle_Qualite_Test.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./QSFSI-05-Controle_Qualite_Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 77 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasercs.sty)
Document Class: beamer 2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (r
cs-revision 332bfd3ce558)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.de
f)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/xxcolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaserequires.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecompatibility.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasefont.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sansmathaccent/sansmathaccent.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetranslator.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-language-
mappings.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetwoscreens.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoverlay.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetitle.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasesection.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframe.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseverbatim.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframesize.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframecomponents.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenotes.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetoc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetemplates.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseboxes.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenavigation.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetheorems.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasethemes.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemedefault
.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthemedefa
ult.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorthemede
fault.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemede
fault.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterthemede
fault.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeCopenha
gen.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesp
lit.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemero
unded.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorthemewh
ale.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorthemeor
chid.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/utf8x.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(./QSFSI-05-Controle_Qualite_Test.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmss.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./QSFSI-05-Controle_Qualite_Test.out) (./QSFSI-05-Controle_Qualite_Test.out)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-bas
ic-dictionary/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-bib
liography-dictionary/translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-env
ironment-dictionary/translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-mon
ths-dictionary/translator-months-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-num
bers-dictionary/translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-the
orem-dictionary/translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
(./QSFSI-05-Controle_Qualite_Test.nav)

Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfauthor' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 22.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(./QSFSI-05-Controle_Qualite_Test.vrb
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) (./code/Boolean.java

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/lmss/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbar' on input line 4.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-0.def)
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.21 }}

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

l.21 }}

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.21 }}

(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on QSFSI-05-Controle_Qualite_Test.log.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Compiles fine for me (TL 2015, Linux), after commenting the `\lstinputlisting` stuff. The error appears after that line, so it's probably some error in your `Boolean.java` file...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: curiously, commenting the `\lstinputlisting` line does not solve the proble for me ... So it's not Boolean.java.

Comment: @anismek: Well, did you update a package manually recently, apart from switching the Fedora versions?

Comment: I was suspecting the mix between `\colorbox` and `\lstinline` but a have a counter example with the same mix working without problems (well in the working example there's no `\tabular` environement) ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : no. For information, passing from Fedora 19 to 22 was not an upgrade but a fresh new install from scratch. Then I just did `sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-full`. Independently, thanks for your interset and your welcome message.

Comment: Removing the `\tabular` environement gives no longer errors ... Also removing all the `\colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{...}}` and keeping the `\tabular` ... So it's kind of the combination of the 3 is somehow no longer working (after swicth of fedora version) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it works with TL15, but breaks in TL14 (which has a slightly older listings).

But imho you are really stressing listings. You are using it inside the argument of \colorbox, inside a tabular, and on top of this you are using braces for the listings argument - something that works but is rather fragile.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tabular}{c}
%\colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline!a!} %works
%\colorbox{blue!5}{\texttt{a}}    %works and much better
\colorbox{blue!5}{\lstinline{a}}  % error
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps `tcolorbox` with `\tcbinputlisting` etc. would be a better approach: No criticism to your solution (+1), of course

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Well I love tcolorbox, but imho it is a bit overkill to use it to get a typewriter letter in a blue box.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : fair enough ... kind of i was lucky this was working with TL13 :) Eeverybody: thanks.